# IE9: button exhibiting odd behavior and not working on first click, only in IE9

Tags: html, onclick, internet-explorer-9

I'm having an issue that I can only reproduce in IE 9, but I have no idea why. When I click on a button in IE 9, if it is the first click on the freshly loaded page, the button will not register the event. If my initial click is outside the button's area and I make a subsequent click on the button, the action is performed.

```
<button type="button" title="Request Quote" class="button btn-quote" onclick="setLocation('/quotes?partsno=188122-B22&amp;mfg=HP&amp;cond=New');">
<span>
<span>Request Quote</span>
</span>
</button>
```

I can only reproduce the issue in IE9. Spoofing Safari with a IE9 user agent string does not reproduce the issue, and the code can be altered to any valid javascript;the onclick still does not get invoked as expected. An example can be found [here](http://www.itpartsconnection.com/hp-188122b22.html), on the Request Quote button:

http://www.itpartsconnection.com/hp-188122b22.html

Thanks Much!

Comment: Unsurprisingly forcing compatibility mode puts a patch on the issue, but I'm not entirely sure why. Also worth noting: there are no IE9 specific tags.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below syntax, that is semantic:

```
<input type="button" title="Request Quote" value="Request Quote" class="button btn-quote" onclick="setLocation('/quotes?partsno=188122-B22&amp;mfg=HP&amp;cond=New');" />
```

Then, do all the CSS based into your `button` and `btn-quote` CSS classes, not the spams.